# What do the arrows in the navigator pane on Xcode indicate?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

In earlier versions of Xcode the source control tool would indicate that you have modified a file by showing a bold 'M' to the right of the file name.

In Xcode 9 I noticed that some of my files now show either an upward or upward facing arrow. What do they indicate?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The arrows that sometimes appear to the right of a file in the navigator is indicating whether you have any files that has not yet been pushed to your remote branch or if you have changes for that file to be pulled from a remote.

The upward pointing arrow indicates you have local changes for that file that have not been pushed to your remote repository.

The downward pointing arrow indicates you have remote changes to that file that you have not fetched yet.

The arrows looks like this in Xcode 9.

[image: Indicates that the file have three **local** commits that have not been pushed yet and 2 commits waiting to be fetched from the remote branch]

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit strange that I still see those arrows even thought all changes been pushed. Is there any way to see what files/changes the numbers are referring to?

Comment: I believe it is a bit broken at the moment. Does it still show if you go "Source Control" -> "Fetch and Refresh Status"

Comment: That "Fetch and Refresh Status" Actually did the Job. Thanks for that. Xcode 9 is Really buggy :|

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I'm assuming you mean the arrows on the left of the text. The down arrow means it is displaying all its contents below. Click it to collapse its contents and it turns to a right arrow. The `M`stands for modified since its last source control commit and if you encounter an `A`, it stands for added.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I mean an arrow next to the M.

Comment: do you have a screenshot of the arrow? might be clearer to understand

Comment: Well...now the arrow disappeared

Comment: oh well, as long as it doesn't affect your project or source control workflow, I wouldn't be too worried about it :)

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know what it means :)

Comment: This is might be late, but the arrow disappears when I do "sync" on the github desktop.